# Comparar un JTextField con un campo cédula de la base de datos

Tags: java, mongodb

Estoy desarrollando un programa con Java y MongoDB, en Netbeans, y debo comparar la información que tiene un JTextField con un campo cédula de la base de datos de MongoDB.

He desarrollado hasta el momento el siguiente código:

```
private void cedulaActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                       

       BasicDBObject existe = new BasicDBObject();


        int cc = Integer.parseInt(cedula.getText()); 
        existe.put("cedula",cc);
        System.out.println(cc);
```

Aquí ingreso el código y lo muestro. Mi inquietud es cómo traer y hacer la comparación. Sé que debo traer la colección de la base de datos en MongoDB y luego compararlo con el JTextField, pero después de buscar por un par de horas, no obtuve el resultado esperado.

Comment: ¿Dónde tienes el problema? 
¿Puedes obtener el valor del JTextField?
¿Puedes obtener el valor necesario de mongo?

Comment: Lo que no puedo hacer es la comparación del valor del campo JTextField con el campo cédula de la base de datos de MongoDB y en caso que éste sea igual, mostrar un mensaje "Usuario existe" si no, "Usuario nuevo"

Comment: Para comparar necesitarías tener dos Strings, entiendo que te falla a la hora de conseguir uno o ambos, pero no se si tu problema es a la hora de traer el dato de la BD o de la GUI

Comment: ¿Cómo estás accediendo a la colección de mongo?